# Save and Update from Datagridview to Access Database

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ms-access-2010

i've been fumbling with this problem for a while now. am trying to update/insert into my access database data from a datagridview on a form.
i've a maskedtextbox that i've masked to suit my primary key. when the mask is completed then automatically, records are read from the database to the textboxes and datagridview as shown in the attached picture.
i did that with this code

```
If STHN_ID.MaskCompleted = True Then
Try
    MyConn = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
                    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT * FROM PersonalData WHERE (STHN_ID='" & STHN_ID.Text & "')"
    Dim STHNCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    dr = STHNCmd.ExecuteReader()
    If dr.HasRows = -1 Then
        While dr.Read
            Fname.Text = dr("Fname").ToString
            LName.Text = dr("Lname").ToString
            Oname.Text = dr("Onames").ToString

            DOB.Text = dr("DOB")

            Title.Text = dr("Title").ToString
            salaryType.Text = dr("SalaryType").ToString
            StaffID.Text = dr("StaffNo").ToString
            SSN.Text = dr("SSN").ToString


            DateEngaged.Text = dr("DateEngaged")


            Category.Text = dr("Category").ToString
            Rank.Text = dr("Rank").ToString
            StaffDept.Text = dr("StaffDept").ToString
            PersonalData.PassportPic.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
            Dim bits As Byte() = CType(dr("PassportPic"), Byte())
            Dim memo As New MemoryStream(bits)
            Dim myimg As New Bitmap(memo)
            PassportPic.Image = myimg

            'da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select [DependantFname],[DependantLname],[DependantOname],[DependantDOB],[Relationship] FROM [DependantData] WHERE [STHN_ID]='" & STHN_ID.Text & "'", MyConn) 'Change items to your database name
            'da.Fill(ds)
            'Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
            'source1.DataSource = view
            'DependantView.DataSource = view

            Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter()
            adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select [DependantFname],[DependantLname],[DependantOname],[DependantDOB],[Relationship] FROM [DependantData] WHERE [STHN_ID]='" & STHN_ID.Text & "'", MyConn)
            Dim builder As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
            'connection.Open()
            Dim myTable As DataTable = New DataTable
            adapter.Fill(myTable)
            DependantView.DataSource = myTable


        End While
        myConnection.Close()


    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No Records for the STHN_ID entered", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        myConnection.Close()
        STHN_ID.Focus()
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    myConnection.Close()
End Try
```

my headache now is to update/insert into the database when records are added/edited in the datagridview based on the STHN_ID entered in the maskedtextbox. any help would be really appreciated.

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylKjj.jpg)

Comment: Where is the code for UPDATE?  That code seems to have nothing to do with the question.  Plus obligatory warning about SQL Parameters instead of string concatenation for queries.

Comment: the code shows how i go the datagridview to load.
the update/insert code is what am fumbling with.
i want the update code to be under a button

Comment: please i've added a sample pic. check it for me.

Comment: Keep the OleDbDataAdapter global and when you want to save changes made to the DataGridView just call the [Update](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the adapter passing the underlying DataGridView DataSource (a datatable) Read carefully the link and its remarks section

Comment: Thanks, i get this error though!!
"Dynamic SQL Generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column informaton"
i used 
              Public adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter()
               Public myTable As DataTable = New DataTable
        Try
                  adapter.Update(myTable)
                   MsgBox("Updated Successfully")
                   Catch ex As Exception
              MsgBox(ex.Message)
           End Try

Comment: @Steve, i get an error saying "Dynamic SQL Generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column informaton"
pls help me out.

Comment: The SELECT from the DependantData table doesn't contain the Primary Key of that table. All the infrastructure behind the Update method is based on the fact that you have retrieved that field/s from the table. If you don't add that field to your SELECT then the Update cannot work. What is the PrimaryKey for the DependantData table?

Comment: @Steve it's, DependantID

Comment: Thanks very much, @Steve, i got it done. Am really grateful.

Answer (score 1):

this is how i got it done!

on maskedtextbox with mask completed this is the code to read from database and load datagridview   ...........

```
    Try
            MyConn = New OleDbConnection
            MyConn.ConnectionString = connString

            con = New OleDbConnection
            con.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = C:\Users\PRINCE\Documents\STHNDatabase.accdb")
            con.Open()

            myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
            myConnection.Open()
            Dim str As String
            str = "SELECT * FROM PersonalData WHERE (STHN_ID='" & STHN_ID.Text & "')"
            Dim STHNCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
            dr = STHNCmd.ExecuteReader()
            If dr.HasRows = -1 Then
                While dr.Read
                    Fname.Text = dr("Fname").ToString
                    LName.Text = dr("Lname").ToString
                    Oname.Text = dr("Onames").ToString

                    DOB.Text = dr("DOB")

                    Title.Text = dr("Title").ToString
                    salaryType.Text = dr("SalaryType").ToString
                    StaffID.Text = dr("StaffNo").ToString
                    SSN.Text = dr("SSN").ToString
                    DateEngaged.Text = dr("DateEngaged")
                    Category.Text = dr("Category").ToString
                    Rank.Text = dr("Rank").ToString
                    StaffDept.Text = dr("StaffDept").ToString
                    PersonalData.PassportPic.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
                    Dim bits As Byte() = CType(dr("PassportPic"), Byte())
                    Dim memo As New MemoryStream(bits)
                    Dim myimg As New Bitmap(memo)
                    PassportPic.Image = myimg


                    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection
                    connection.ConnectionString = connString


                    adapt = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select [DependentID],[DependantFname],[DependantLname],[DependantOname],[DependantDOB],[Relationship],[STHN_ID] FROM [DependantData] WHERE [STHN_ID]='" & STHN_ID.Text & "'", con)
                    ds = New DataSet
                    adapt.Fill(ds, "DependantData")
                    DependantView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

                End While
                myConnection.Close()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("No Records for the STHN_ID entered", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
                myConnection.Close()
                STHN_ID.Focus()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            myConnection.Close()
        End Try
```

and on the SaveButton Click this is the code.....

```
    Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click
    Try
        builder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapt)
        adapt.Update(ds, "DependantData")
        MsgBox("Updated Successfully")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

thanks once again. really appreciate it

Comment: Good, but now, please dedicate a bit of your time to learn how to write a [parameterized query](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) Your code is very dangerous and weak. For example try to put a single quote in whatever you type in the  STHN_ID textbox